# Is there an option to toggle "Open using Rosetta" value for a specific app using Terminal?

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-big-sur, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I'm really tired of checking this option manually for Xcode, which I cannot duplicate due to its size... maybe there is a way to create some kind of shortcut to launch an app (Xcode in my case) with the specific value of "Open using Rosetta"?

Note: this question relates only to Apple Silicon Macs.

Example of the "Open using Rosetta" option in Finder:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LaunchServices` are keeping track.

See `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`: `Architectures for arm64` dictionary.

Comment: I've decided to create a tiny menu bar app instead of writing a command each time.. I think I will make it public and then post a link here ;)

Comment: any updates on that? :)

Answer (score 4):

Modifying `com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` only works after reboot. You could call the private function `_LSSetArchitecturePreferenceForApplicationURL` defined in `CoreServices.framework`. This is what finder does when you check/uncheck "Open Using Rosetta."

I have created a small utility that does this: https://github.com/tapthaker/SetArchPrefForURL

Answer (score 2):

**How to Open using Rosetta in Xcode 14.3**

If you are using Xcode 14.3 or later or M1 still need to run it under Rosetta, you might notice that the option to open Xcode in Rosetta is no longer available.

[image]

How to Open using Rosetta in Xcode 14.3

The good news is Apple didn't stop supporting Rosetta (yet). On the contrary, They make it more manageable.

Instead of making the Xcode run using Rosetta, in Xcode 14.3, we can select destination architecture per project right within Xcode.[image]

Comment: more detail: https://sarunw.com/posts/open-using-rosetta-in-xcode-14-3/

Comment: In Xcode 15, you have to select "Show All Run Destinations" instead of "Destination Architecture."  Then, you'll get the option to use a simulator with Rosetta.